# Hot reload in Vue does not work inside a Docker container

Tags: docker, vue.js

I was trying to dockerize my existing simple vue app , following on this tutorial from vue webpage https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/cookbook/dockerize-vuejs-app.html. I successfully created the image and the container. My problem is that when I edit my code like "hello world" in App.vue it will not automatically update or what they called this hot reload ? or should I migrate to the latest Vue so that it will work ?

`docker run -it --name=mynicevue -p 8080:8080 mynicevue/app`

```
FROM node:lts-alpine

# install simple http server for serving static content
RUN npm install -g http-server

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

# build app for production with minification
# RUN npm run build

EXPOSE 8080
CMD [ "http-server", "serve" ]
```

**EDIT:**

Still no luck. I comment out the npm run build. I set up also vue.config.js and add this code

```
  module.exports = {
    devServer: {
        watchOptions: {
            ignored: /node_modules/,
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000,
        },
    }
};
```

then I run the container like this
`docker run -it --name=mynicevue -v %cd%:/app -p 8080:8080 mynicevue/app

when the app launches to browser I get this error in terminal and the browser is whitescreen

"GET /" Error (404): "Not found"

Can someone help me please of my Dockerfile what is wrong or missing so that I can play my vue app using docker ?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I'd suggest using a host-based Node setup for a live-reloading developer setup.  Uncomment the `RUN npm run build` in the Dockerfile, and use the (immutable) Docker image when you're going to deploy the code elsewhere.

Comment: What do  you mean host-base Node ? And also immutable Docker image ?

Comment: (a) Assuming you have Node installed already (and it's very easy to install if not) you can just run `npm run start` in your source directory; you don't have to do anything special to make it be aware of the host's source directory.  (b) Once you `docker build` an image you can't change it or the source code in it, you need to `docker build` a new one.  This makes Docker a little less suitable for your day-to-day development work.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Okay I tried your project in my local and here's how you do it.

#### Dockerfile

```sh
FROM node:lts-alpine

# bind your app to the gateway IP
ENV HOST=0.0.0.0

# make the 'app' folder the current working directory
WORKDIR /app

# copy both 'package.json' and 'package-lock.json' (if available)
COPY package*.json ./

# install project dependencies
RUN npm install

# copy project files and folders to the current working directory (i.e. 'app' folder)
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8080

ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]
```

Use this command to run the docker image after you build it:

```sh
docker run -v ${PWD}/src:/app/src -p 8080:8080 -d mynicevue/app
```

---

#### Explanation

1. It seems that Vue is expecting your app to be bound to your gateway IP when it is served from within a container. Hence `ENV HOST=0.0.0.0` inside the Dockerfile.
2. You need to mount your `src` directory to the running container's `/app/src` directory so that the changes in your local filesystem directly reflects and visible in the container itself.
3. The way in Vue to watch for the file changes is using `npm run dev`, hence `ENTRYPOINT [ "npm", "run", "dev" ]` in Dockerfile

Comment: should I need to use docker-compose to have this CHOKIDAR_USEPOLLING ? I don't want to use first the docker-compose I want to try without using docker-compose is this possible ?

Comment: I updated my post as what you suggested still no luck, I get "GET /" Error (404): "Not found" when sharing volume

Comment: should I replace the npm run build to npm run serve ?

Comment: same question @jemz . you know the answer whether we need to replace build with serve ? if so my docker compose up is taking too long not finishing npm run serve. pls help

Answer (score 2):

if you tried previous answers and still doesn't work , try adding `watch:{usePolling: true}` to `vite.config.js` file

```js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite'
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue'

// https://vitejs.dev/config/
export default defineConfig({
  plugins: [vue()],
  server: {
    host: true,
    port: 4173,
    watch: {
      usePolling: true
    }
  }
})
```

Comment: this `vite.config.js` should be presented in docker container src directory ?

Comment: @VivekRahul yes

Comment: the port `4173` is what i too need to use ? or i should use my api listening port ?

Comment: @VivekRahul use what ever port number you want, your vite server will be listening on that port , in my case , 4371 is mapped to the 3000 of the docker container , so my app will be listening to 3000